# Editor border in VS Code for specific tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was trying to add a border to an extension that I have been working on, I have 2 main concerns.

1. **How do I add a border around a tab in the editor.**
2. **Now how do I extend this to, only those tabs should have borders that I chose.**

I was looking into these settings : [Theme Color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) but I cant find anything that can help. (PS : I may just have missed it)

For a better visual I am expecting something like this:

[image: SQL Developer]

Answer (score 0):

The default text editor can not be customized this way since it has to fit into the VSCode design guidelines. Themes can probably do it but would have to be applied globally for the same reason.

Custom editors for extensions can be made using the [Custom Editor API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors).

Alternatively, check the [UX guidelines](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/overview) for a VSCode-ish way to achieve your goal.